# how to override function of mongoose plugin?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I have a plugin in mongoose and for each schema i am doing the following

```
var user = new Schema({});
user.plugin(myplugin);
user.statics.createCustomDoc = function() {
.....
}
```

The problem is the createCustomDoc method is also defined in myplugin.
Now i want to override `createCustomDoc` of myplugin with the method defined as user.statics.createCustomDoc.

Currently the method called is from the plugin not the one i wrote in user.statics.createCustomDoc.

How do i do that.?

Of course i do not want to change the name of function nor i want to remove the plugin nor i want to change code of plugin.

Comment: I have the same issue I need to save some data as original and to other collection with slight modification, I would like to override mongoose CRUD to do just that.

Comment: I just tested this with mongoose 4.1.7 and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I faced similar issue while overriding mongoose query functions and tried something like this and it works*

```
//store reference to original myPlugin createCustomDoc function
var createCustomDoc = user.statics.createCustomDoc;

//override that function
user.statics.createCustomDoc = function (options, callback) {
   var self = this; 
   //after your code, call original function
   createCustomDoc.call(self, options, callback);

}
```